# LINQ to XML - VB.NET to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-xml

have the following in my project, written in VB.NET:

```
 Dim items = From item In rssFeed.Elements("forecast").Elements("tabular").Elements("time") _
                    Select New WetherItem With {.time=item.Element("windDirection").Attribute("code").Value }
```

How is this written in C #?

I have tried the following ...

```
XElement rssFeed = XElement.Load(@"http://www.yr.no/sted/Norge/Rogaland/Karm%C3%B8y/Torvastad/varsel.xml");
var items = from item in rssFeed.Elements("forecast").Elements("tabular").Elements("time")
select new WetherItem { .time=item.Element("windDirection").Attribute("code").Value };
```

But I get the error message from

> rssFeed.Elements("forecast").Elements("tabular").Elements("time")
>
> Error 5   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for
>   source type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. 
>   'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive
>   for 'System.Linq'?    c:\users\\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\Database1\Database1\SqlStoredProcedure1.cs  32  30  Database1

I have reference to System.XML.Linq and System.Data.Linq

Comment: As a side note: In VB, you can shorten this to `From item In rssFeed.<forecast>.<tabular>.<time> Select New WetherItem With {.time = item.<windDirection>.@code}`.

Answer (score 2):

In the C# code file on top you will see the using statements, in there add:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Also remove `.` from `.time` in your select statement, if the property name is `time`

Comment: I run. NET 4.5, and Target Platform to SQL Server 2012. I can not find System.Linq in the reference list. By the way this is a SQL CLR

Comment: You need to add reference to `System.Core.dll` from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5, you may see this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/e794e949-ed31-4c66-80b3-bd635f63675a

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
A reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Core.dll' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add using statements at the top of the file, and your query in c#:

```
var items = from item in rssFeed.Elements("forecast".Elements("tablular").Elements("time")
            select new WetherItem { 
                           time = item.Element("windDirection").Attribute("code").Value
                       };
```

Comment: I have now :) Error 4 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'? c:\users\<user>\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Database1\Database1\SqlStoredProcedure1.cs 34 26 Database1

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unusual problem, that even i faced while working on a app, because neither VS clearly specifies what the problem is nor there are proper ans to this problem. One ans, I think may be is :-

Add another reference to your project :- 
**using System.Linq;** *apart from* **using System.Xml.Linq;**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

The errors might go & the project will build.

---

For more help reference this article :-

[problem with using refrence to System.Xml.Linq](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/23a2e0b1-63e5-4aa7-ba46-0fca173bf348/query-xdocument-using-linq)